# Adding row to table with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to add row with button click in table(Add Row). I am trying to add 2 fields dynamically.
1) slno
2) Date/ Time.

My problems :
1) Row is not getting added.
2) How to assign datepicker to "Date /Time" field, added dynamically.

Jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RXzs7/12/

Pl help.

html code :

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker({ minDate:"-1m",maxDate:"0"  });
    });
}); 
</script>

<body>

  <div id="lpage_container">
    <div class="lform_container">
      <h3>DETAILS OF LOCAL CONVEYANCE EXPENSES :</h3>

      <form id="localexpenses" action="">
        <table  summary="local expense" id="localexpense_table" width="500" border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="1%" align="center"><strong>Sl.
              No.</strong></th>

              <th width="7%" align="center">
              <strong>Date/Time</strong></th>          
              <th width="8%" align="center">
              <strong>Remove</strong></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr>
              <td width="1%" align="center"><input type="text"
              name="lsrno_00" id="srno_00" size="1" value="0"></td>

              <td width="7%" align="center"><input type="text" class="date"
              name="ldate_00" id="ldate_00" value="" size="8"></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <table summary="local buttons" width="500" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><input type="button" value="Add Row"
            id="add_ExpenseRowlocal">            
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div><!-- END subject_marks -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
```

JS code :

```
$(function(){
    // GET ID OF last row and increment it by one
    var $lastChar =1, $newRow;
    $get_lastID = function(){
        var $id = $('#localexpense_table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("name");
        $lastChar = parseInt($id.substr($id.length - 2), 10);
        console.log('GET id: ' + $lastChar + ' | $id :'+$id);
        $lastChar = $lastChar + 1;
        $newRow = "<tr> \
        <td><input type='text' name='lsrno_0"+$lastChar+"' value='0"+$lastChar+"' size='1'readonly /></td> \
        <td><input type='text' class='date' name='ldate_0"+$lastChar+"' id='date_0"+$lastChar+"' size='8'/></td> \
        <td><input type='button' value='Remove' class='del_ExpenseRowlocal' /></td> \
    </tr>";
        return $newRow;
    };

    // ***** -- START ADDING NEW ROWS
    $('#add_ExpenseRowlocal').on("click", function(){ 

        if($lastChar <= 9){
            $get_lastID();
            $('#localexpense_table tbody').append($newRow);
        } else {
            alert("Reached Maximum Rows!");
        }
    });
        $(document).on("click", ".del_ExpenseRowlocal", function(){ 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $lastChar = $lastChar-2;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: First step add jQuery in fiddle. (Option present on left top)

Comment: Please fix your fiddle to actually show the behaviour you have.  You should not have a script block in the HTML and then the script block I suspect.  Plus add jQuery as @Karna said.  At the moment nothing happens when you click add row in the fiddle

Comment: @ karna, done as you indicated. updated fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/SqA9a/15/

Comment: pl suggest for datepicker in "Date" field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jQuery version are you using?  In your fiddle you have not added jQuery via the framework tab but under extenral resources you have two versions: 1.6.2 and 1.11.0.  When I try and run it I get an error in the console that `$().on`is not a function.  `.on()` came in jQuery 1.7 so if you are using 1.6.2 then you cannot use `.on()`.

As for the date picker, when you run

```
$('.date').each(function() {
   $(this).datepicker({ minDate:"-1m",maxDate:"0"
});
```

in your document ready you add a date picker to all field with class date *which currently exist*.  You must add the date picker to the new date fields after you have added the row to the DOM.  Something like

```
$('.date', $('#localexpense_table tbody tr').filter(':last')).each(function() {
   $(this).datepicker({ minDate:"-1m",maxDate:"0"  });
});
```

after your `.append()` call should work.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EZXB/1/) (needs some styles fixing for the added rows)

Comment: As a side note, you shpuld think through your add row functions a bit bettter.  For example $get_lastID does not *not* get the alst id but instead generates a new row.  It should be renamed.  Also it returns the HTML for the new row so you do not need to have a variable external to that function to contain that new row - better to simply use the return value.

Comment: Great!. Actually i am Instrumentation engineer by profession. As i know VB my co has given me this development work. I don't know html codes.Sorry, for troubling you. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: very helpful !!